# ChartJS datasets with one data value

Tags: javascript, chart.js

It can possible to set only one data in datasets?

Here example:

```
var barChartData = {
 labels: ['1 Aug'],
 datasets: [{
      label: 'Sales',
      borderWidth: 0,
      data: [10],
      borderWidth: 3
  }]
};
```

If it possible then why can not data show me in a chart?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to set `point: { radius: 1 }` for one data value.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');

var barChartData = {
 labels: ['1 Aug'],
 datasets: [{
      label: 'Sales',
      borderWidth: 0,
      data: [10],
      borderWidth: 3
  }]
};

var myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: barChartData,
options: {
    elements: {
        line: {
            tension: 0.5
        },
        point: {
            radius: 1
        }
    }
  }
});
```